# How to find the common value in the view?

Tags: xpages

My application is using xpages, I try to find the common value in the view.

Imagine view1 has the following values: (Location and Officer are the column name in the view)

```
Location  | Officer
Australia | Peter
Belgium   | John
Chile     | Ben
Germany   | Charlie
Italy     | Mike
Singapore | Tom
```

Imagine view2 has the following values: (Item and Location are the column name in the view)

```
Item     | Location
Book     | Brazil
Book     | Italy
Fiction  | Singapore
Journal  | Australia
Magazine | Australia
Magazine | Austria
Movie    | Portugal
Movie    | Spain
```

To enhance the application, I have to compare values between two views and define the item is a common item or a specific item.

In view2, if the item has more than one location, then that item is a common item. If the item has one location, that item is a specific item. For example, in view2, book, magazine and movie are the common item whereas fiction and journal are the specific item.

From the code below, it can show the comparison between view1 and view2.

```
var keyvalue = sessionScope.keyvalue;
var text = ""; 
var message = "";
var item_msg = ""; //show whether the item is common item or specific item
var view1 = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "view1", keyvalue , 0)); // use keyvalue to lookup in view1
var view2 = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "view2", view1 , 1)); // use view1 value to lookup in view2

text +="<table><tr><td><u><b>header</u></td></tr>"

for(var x = 0; x < view1.length; x++) 
{
     message = "value does not match";
     for(var y = 0; y < view2.length; y++) 
    {
       if(view1[x] == view2[y]) 
       {
            message = "value matches";
            break;
        }   
    }

 text +=("<tr><td>" + view1[x] + "</td><td>" + message  + "</td><td>"+item_msg+"</td></tr>");
}

return text +"</table>";
```

I suppose the result will look this:

```
Australia | value matches        | common item
Belgium   | value does not match | not available as value does not match
Chile     | value matches        | specific item
Germany   | value does not match | not available as value does not match
Italy     | value matches        | common item
Singapore | value matches        | common item
```

Regarding to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713626/xpages-compare-values-between-two-views),  I can use for loop and @DbLookup to compare values between two views.

However I don't have idea to show the item is common item or specific item because I am not sure which is the key that I can use for @DbLookup.

I read this https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/NotesName_sample_JavaScript_code_for_XPages about common name but I am afraid it is not the common value that I am looking for.

Grateful if someone let me know how to get the common value from the view please. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your issue or question. We don't know what the key in your dblookup should be, you're the programmer...

Comment: @zerohero, thanks your comment. So far as I know, if I use DbLookup, the key is to retrieve a value. Actually, I have been used the location in view1 as a key to lookup in view2 but the result was not successful, therefore I remove that part of the code in the post to make the code clear. I still working on this part, so I may improve this post later.

Comment: why is the for loop not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

This will be much less painful with repeat controls, and is one of the key benefits of that component.

Create a repeat control whose source is view1, defining the `var` property, which will be how you get a handle on the current element being iterated. Within that have a component that looks up to view2 and finds the count of entries matching the key from the current element being iterated. From that, you can find if the current element is common or not.

If you're not familiar with repeat controls, get familiar. It shouldn't be hard to find resources to demonstrate their use, and NotesIn9 is the place I would recommend starting if you're unsure.

I suspect you will struggle to find anyone with experience of coding the solution in XPages the way you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be an easy task if you use Java and create a Map or List object. Loop through the first view, then loop through the second view to determine if they are common or whatever you were trying to relate them to each other. Then tie a repeat to a List to display the values.